# Installing AMD Radeon HD 7400M series fedora 20

Tags: drivers, fedora

I just installed fedora 20 on my second pc and its running pretty hot, I found a driver on the site http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64.

I unpacked it and I tried `sudo sh amd-driver-installer-13.35.1005-x86.x86_64.run` and I get this

```
Supported adapter detected.
Check if system has the tools required for installation.
fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers for 3.7 release./lib/modules/3.11.10-301.fc20.i686+PAE/build/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.
One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system. Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver.
Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without the tools.
Forcing install will disable AMD hardware acceleration and may make your system unstable. Not recommended.
```

and I don't know how to solve it and I have already tried:

```
yum install kernel-devel kernel-headers gcc -y
```

http://www.amd.com/US/PRODUCTS/NOTEBOOK/GRAPHICS/7000M/7400M/Pages/radeon-7400m.aspx

Comment: I'm interested in the answer to this question as well. Having the same issue. From what I can gather, the person maintaining the catalyst driver package is no longer supporting the driver. kmod-fglrx no longer exists within the rpmfusion repositories.

Comment: You might also try newer Fedora (with F24 right around the corner) to see if improvements in the open source driver help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue.  Make sure fedora is completely updated using yum and that issue should go away.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the rpmfusion-nonfree repositories [1] and install the driver from that repository:

```
 yum install kmod-fglrx
```

[1] http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration

Comment: This works only through f19. The package is orphaned and no one seems to be planning to adopt.